# Implementing DTLS with indy UDP client (delphi)

Tags: delphi, udp, indy, dtls

I need to implement DTLS in Delphi using TIdUDPClient. I understand its based on TLS and so I have been digging my way though the OpenSSL indy components but the UDP client does not have an IOHandler so I'm not sure its usable for UDP communication.

Is there a DTLS Delphi implementation that I have not found or could someone point me towards a solution?

Comment: IOHandlers are used only for TCP, not for UDP. Indy does not natively support DTLS at this time, though some of OpenSSL's DTLS functions and record types are implemented in Indy's `IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders` unit. Indy's UDP components can send and receive arbitrary UDP packets, but you will have to use the DTLS functions manually to encode/decode the TLS content of those packets as needed. Sorry, I don't have a tutorial for you, I have never worked with DTLS before. I'm sure you can find an OpenSSL DTLS tutorial somewhere and then apply the UDP portions to Indy.